# Windows Server 2012 refuses to install feature

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-server, windows

Good morning,
I'm having some issues with adding the File Server Resource Manager role to WS2012. In fact the role has already been added and configured, but at each reboot it disappears and cannot be used.

When I try to reinstall it I get an error which in turn requires me to reboot the server to add any new feature. When I do so, I can see the role present again in the start menu. I can open it, use it, configure it, but if I check the roles and features wizard in the server manager it appears as "uninstalled".

If I reboot the server a second time, I'm back at square 1. It looks to me like there is some kind of corruption with the installation package, as any other feature can be added or removed without the slightest issue. If it can help, the server is a RODC.

If you need any other info just ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old question but I'll leave this here as this post was one of the first search results.

I had the same issue while trying to install Distributed Scan Management (FSRM is a prerequisite). Looks like the FSRM installation fails because it needs to add some local security groups to the server, which is not possible since it's a RODC.

Microsoft's 'solution' is just to install FSRM before promoting the server to a RODC:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2973343/

Far as I can tell, this is the only way to do it. I ended up demoting the RODC (preserving metadata) and was then able to install FSRM successfully. I then promoted the server back to a RODC using the existing computer account. Fun stuff.